# Undefined result from `getTransaction` method call

Tags: web3.js

I get so many undefined transactions with this code:

```
const transaction = await connection.getTransaction(programSignature.signature);
```

Is it normal?
To give you a context, I'm using it in a loop and call `getTransaction` function 18k times per runtime to get all the transactions of a specific program.

Comment: Can you share the function that's generating `programSignature` and describe its inputs over the 18k runs?

Comment: Until the transaction is confirmed, `getTransaction()` will return undefined.

Comment: please post solutions as answers, not comments

Comment: It felt too short to justify a response :P but ok

Comment: Are the transactions over a long period of time? Depending on the RPC you are connecting to, some don't have full history so you are limited to how far back you can go.

Comment: @CallumM https://github.com/ricardocr987/snapshot/blob/master/index.ts programSignature comes from a vector programSignatures that comes from a function where i do a loop until i get all the transaction history of the specific program, know is working correctly I don't remember what I did lol maybe the while after the line I posted

Answer (score 1):

Until the transaction is confirmed, `getTransaction()` will return `undefined`.

The RPC endpoints [return null](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#results-42) when the transaction is not found or not confirmed. This is just [propagated](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/0fff5b8bf86721ec88bb69d142a41cc12f6a6cf9/web3.js/src/connection.ts#L3734) to the caller by the web3.js client.